# ldap_add: Constraint violation (19) - additional info: cn required

Tags: ldap, ldapjs

I am trying to add a new user in LDAP by using the below command:

```
ldapadd -H ldap://localhost:1389 -x -D cn=root -w secret -f ./user.ldif
```

**user.ldif** file contains the data as

```
dn: cn=ldapjs, ou=users, o=myhost
objectClass: unixUser
cn: ldapjs
shell: /bin/bash
description: Created via ldapadd
```

When I try to run the ldapadd command, I got the below error and I could not find where I made the mistakes:

```
**ERROR**
ldap_add: Constraint violation (19)
    matched DN: ou=users, o=myhost
    **additional info: cn required**
```

Here I am running the **ldapjs server** in the url: 'ldap://127.0.0.1:1389' with root mode.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurred due to the ldapjs server API. The example code shared in ldapjs.org is not suitable for the latest ldapjs API. We can fix the issue by changing req.dn.rdn[0].cn to req.dn.rdn[0].attrs.cn